# styled component multiple override css no effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a React component styled using styled-components, but can it be apply style again? My button is a react component

```
import Button from "./Button";
```

Then somewhere else I add margin-top, it don't apply the style.

```
//margin-top has no effect?
const ButtonStyled = styled(Button)`
  margin-top: 100px;
`;

export default function App() {
  return <ButtonStyled>My button</ButtonStyled>;
}
```

Demo here
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-montalcini-l47kp?file=/src/App.js:144-150

Comment: What do you mean? The margin is being applied. You’re just experiencing something called “margin collapse” (I think)

Comment: @evolutionxbox you can try to add background: red; it doesn't reflect anything, it's not a margin issue.

Comment: An easy way is to up the selector specificity. Wrap all the styles in `&&& {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the `styled` function to work, the component must accept a `className` prop. Now, when you define `Button`:

```
const Button = ({ children }, props) => {
  return <ButtonStyled {...props}>{children}</ButtonStyled>;
};
```

You try to spread the props to `ButtonStyled`, which is good, you just mis typed the place of `props`. Try this:

```
const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <ButtonStyled {...props}>{children}</ButtonStyled>;
};
```

This way, the `className` prop (which is applied by `styled()`) will be passed onto `StyledButton`.

Comment: this is the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have seen two options to override the css.

- Wrapper the component
- Through props

```
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  ${(props) => {
    return css`
      margin-top: 10px;
      width: 200px;
      padding: 16px 0;
      border: 1px solid;
      color: black;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 900;
      border-radius: 5px;
      ${props.newStyled}
    `;
  }}
`;

const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <ButtonStyled {...props}>{children}</ButtonStyled>;
};

// OPTION 1: WRAPPER THE COMPONENT
function Question7_option1() {
  const DivStyled = styled.div`
    button {
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
`;
  return (<DivStyled>
    <Button>Button</Button>
  </DivStyled>);
}

// OPTION 2: NEW STYLES THROUGH PROPS
function Question7_option2() {
  const newStyled = css`
    margin-top: 100px;
`;
  return (<Button newStyled={newStyled}>Button</Button>);
}

export default Question7_option2;
```

I hope I've helped you